# django-sphinx BuildExcerpts

Tags: python, django, django-sphinx

I'm trying to use BuildExcerpts in django sphinx.  My view looks something like this:

```
q = request.GET.get('q', '')

my_model_list = MyModel.search.query(q).set_options(passages=True, passages_opts={
                        'before_match':"<font color='red'>",
                        'after_match':'</font>',
                        'chunk_separator':' ... ',
                        'around':6,
                         })
```

When I run this I get an `AssertionError`

Here's the trace:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\django\myproject\myapp\views.py" in home_page
  81.             my_model_list = remove_duplicates(list(my_model_list))
File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.3-py2.5.egg\djangosphinx\models.py" in __iter__
  243.         return iter(self._get_data())
File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.3-py2.5.egg\djangosphinx\models.py" in _get_data
  422.             self._result_cache = list(self._get_results())
File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.3-py2.5.egg\djangosphinx\models.py" in _get_results
  603.                             r['passages'] = self._get_passages(queryset[r['id']], results['fields'], words)
File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.3-py2.5.egg\djangosphinx\models.py" in _get_passages
  657.         passages_list = client.BuildExcerpts(docs, self._index, words, opts)
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.3-py2.5.egg\djangosphinx\apis\api278\__init__.py" in BuildExcerpts
  791.          assert(isinstance(doc, str))

Exception Type: AssertionError at /
Exception Value:
```

I'm not really sure what's going on.  Anyone have an experience with this?

I'm using django 1.2.3, Sphinx 0.9.9, and django-sphinx 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who are having similar problems, here is what I had to do to fix it.

Go to your django-sphinx install folder and open up models.py.  On line 650, you need to replace these two lines:

```
docs = [getattr(instance, f) for f in fields]
if isinstance(self._passages_opts, dict):
```

with

```
 docs = [getattr(instance, f) for f in fields]

 for index, doc in enumerate(docs):
     if (not (isinstance(doc, str)) and (not isinstance(doc, unicode))):
                         docs[index] = repr(doc)

  if isinstance(self._passages_opts, dict):
```

Then you can access your excerpts like this in your view:

```
for r in results_set:
   print r.sphinx.get('passages')
```

or in the template like this:

```
{{record.sphinx.passages.content|safe}}
```

Comment: Looks like the source for this fix is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-sphinx/WNL3a5h3MU8/nlGpujbfMEYJ